# horizontal alignment of options in ipywidgets

Tags: python, html, css, ipywidgets

How to align items horizontally in multi-select menu?

Currently [this](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Widget%20List.html#SelectMultiple) gives me a vertical alignment of options:

```
widgets.SelectMultiple(options=['option-1','option-2', 'option-3', 'option-4', 'option-5'],
                            rows=5, layout=widgets.Layout(width='440px'))
```

I am looking for a way to align all the options in a single row.

Comment: try = select option{display:inline-block;}

Comment: Yeah, I tried `inline-block` as well as `table-cell` for display value inside Layout definition. Did not work