# Control of layout ipywidgets in jupyter notebook

Tags: layout, jupyter, ipywidgets

I have some problems understanding how to control the flexbox of ipywidgets in jupyter notebook. According to the [docs](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Widget%20Styling.html) this should be possible, however my styling code (see below) does not result in the desired layout. I checked on stack and found a [good resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58235440/horizontal-alignment-of-options-in-ipywidgets) that seemed to work for people there, however running the code still does not provide the desired the result.

## The problem

I would like control to build somewhat more complex layouts. In this case particularly the goal is to have the sliders vertically next to the matpltolib plot:

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import subplots
from IPython.display import display
import ipywidgets as ipy
import numpy as np

# setup figure
n = 10
fig, ax = subplots(figsize = (5,5))
h = ax.imshow(np.random.rand(n, n))

# show random mesh
def update(idx):
    h.set_data(np.random.rand(n, n))
    fig.canvas.flush_events()
    fig.canvas.draw()
slider = ipy.IntSlider(min = 0, max = 10, orientation = 'vertical')
widget = ipy.interactive(update, idx = slider)

layout = ipy.Layout(display = 'flex',\
                   flex_flow = 'row',\
                   justify_content = 'space-between',\
                   align_items = 'center',\
                   )
widgets = ipy.HBox(widget.children[::-1], layout = layout)
display(widgets)
```

However it results in [image]

How can I force the layout to be horizontal columns using ipywidgets in jupyter notebook?

Answer (score 1):

Try specifically creating an output widget to contain your chart, and then placing that as one of your children in a HBox:

```py
from IPython.display import display, clear_output
import ipywidgets as ipy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# setup figure
n = 10

out = ipy.Output()

# show random mesh
def update(idx):
    with out:
        clear_output()
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (5,5))
        h = ax.imshow(np.random.rand(n, n))
        h.set_data(np.random.rand(n, n))
        fig.canvas.flush_events()
        fig.canvas.draw()
        plt.show()

slider = ipy.IntSlider(min = 0, max = 10, orientation = 'vertical')
widget = ipy.interactive(update, idx = slider)

layout = ipy.Layout(
#     display = 'flex',
#                    flex_flow = 'row',
#                    justify_content = 'space-between',
#                    align_items = 'center',
                   )
widgets = ipy.HBox(children=(slider, out), layout = layout)
display(widgets)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, however rebuilding the figure causes flickering and is not prefered; I'll have a look at this output object, thanks!